# PuTTY can't launch X programs when IPv6 is disabled

Tags: putty, ipv6

I'm accessing my Raspberry Pi 3 with PuTTY, and using X11 programs like GParted through ssh connection. It was perfectly working until I turned off IPv6 by adding the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

It does disable IPv6, but it makes X11 programs stop starting. It always shows message something like

```
pi@RPi-Dev:~$ sudo -E gparted
[sudo] password for pi:

(gpartedbin:1173): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Why does disabling ipv6 cause it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't disable IPv6. It is not going away and you will need it sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

The method I used to specify disabling command in `/etc/sysctl.conf` wasn't the right way. It did disabled IPv6 like other Debian based distributions, but what I had to do was adding following command in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

```
ipv6.disable=1
```

Everything worked fine after adding the command in the file.